# jQuery: html() function does not match real HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the EXACT html content of a div.

When using the html() function from jQuery, the result does not match the actual content.

Please check this fiddle and click on the black square:

http://jsfiddle.net/qRska/6/

The code:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color:#000000; cursor:pointer;">

    <div id="INSIDE" style="background-color:#ffffff; border-style:none;"></div>

</div>

$('#mydiv').click(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

jQuery change the color to RGB format and remove the border-style attribute.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is not jquery, this is relative to browser's behaviour

Comment: Browsers do this translation when parsing HTML to create the DOM.

Comment: As documented: [This method uses the browser's `innerHTML` property. Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters.](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html1)

Comment: Your fiddle is returning the exact html from inside the clicked item, do you want it to return html for the container as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The browser consumes the HTML, generates a DOM, then **discards the HTML**. `innerHTML` (which is what `.html()` eventually hits) gives a serialisation of the DOM back to HTML.

If you want to get the raw HTML, then you'll need to use `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch the source code of the current URL and then process it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is unfortunately not possible. The original HTML is not available after it is parsed by the browser, so you have to jump through some hoops to prevent the browser from processing it.

One possible solution that I've used before is to wrap the HTML in comment tags, which would remain unchanged by the browser. You can then extract the comment using jQuery's `.text()` method; strip out the comment tags with string replacement; make the necessary changes to the markup; and then inject it back into the document.

The other alternative is to use AJAX to load the HTML. Make sure you set the `contentType` to `'text'` so it doesn't get processed by the browser.